# cURL POST of custom binary data (not form contents)

Tags: php, post, curl, http-post

The problem the following code piece successfully sends POST request but doesn't send the data in $sendStream (the stream is valid and contains data - this has been verified):

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/x-rethync-request'));
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_INFILE, $sendStream);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, stream_length($sendStream));
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

$response = curl_exec($request);
```

I've read probably all cURL POST-related posts here on SO, but no luck. Why is the data not posted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The missing piece was

```
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
```

The PHP documentation mentions this option briefly and nothing suggests that the option should be set. Still at least some (if not all) versions of cURL don't post data despite it's specified via CURLOPT_INFILE, unless CURLOPT_UPLOAD is also set.

NOTE: when you use this method to send the data, the response header will contain `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` first, followed by `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and so on. So when you parse response headers, beware of the first 100 Continue response (you'll need to strip it).

Comment: Thank you - that was the missing piece I was looking for as well.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you can send string as stream.
With PHP you could do it with few lines of code.
`$someString = 'String content';
$stream = fopen('php://memory','r+');
fwrite($stream, $someString );
$dataLength = ftell($stream);
rewind($stream);`
Then adding those lines that were mentioned you can send binary data.
`CURLOPT_INFILE => $stream
 CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $dataLength
 CURLOPT_UPLOAD => 1`

Comment: @WojciechJakubas I am not sure that I understand the point of the comment. Yes, you can send the data from a memory stream, however the problem was different - the missing parameter caused cURL not to send anything. The origin of the data was probably not the source of the problem.